# Override Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement.php

Tags: magento2, overrides

I want to override the function `getLabelHtml` in `Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement.php`

I make a copy of this file in my `\app\code\CompanyName\ModuleName\Model\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement.php`

and I create a file in `\app\code\CompanyName\ModuleName\etc\adminhtml\di.xml`
with this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement" type="CompanyName\ModuleName\Model\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement"/>
</config>
```

and then I compile the module.
But is not work. Not override.

Answer (score 1):

Same as on Magento 1, you cannot rewrite abstract classes.
The class you are trying to rewrite is an abstract class.
The preferences you declare in `di.xml` are used only when instantiating classes that have other classes as dependencies.
In you case, in case there is a class that has a dependency an instance of `Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement` it will work, but most probably there are no such classes.

Even if you declare a preference for the abstract class, the classes that extend the abstract class will still extend the original class, not yours.
I think the way to go on this case is to create a `before|after|around` plugin for the method `getLabelHtml` for your abstract class

Comment: You can also write plugins for abstract classes.

Comment: @fschmengler. I wasn't sure about that. Thanks for clearing it.

Comment: Do you have any example how to create it and rewrite the function getLabelHtml?